# Border to margin in HTML

Tags: html, css, margin

I am new to HTML programming. Is it possible to make a border to the margin instead of the padding? I need this just for design purposes only.

Comment: Thinking this should be tagged ``CSS``...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The border goes between the padding and the margin. If you don't want a margin, set the margin to 0 and that way the border is on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a border to the margin instead of the padding?

Yes. The closest way I can think of to achieve this effect is using the CSS [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

This clips any backgrounds in the element not to be rendered in the border region, thus treating it like a margin rather than padding.

Below is an example of the difference:

```css
div {
  border: 5px dashed #000; /* to see through border */
  background-color: #0FF; /* to show extent of background */
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.adjusted {
  background-clip: padding-box; /* corrects extent of background */
}
```

```html
<div>Default Border</div>
<div class="adjusted">Corrected Border</div>
```

In the "corrected" div, the border becomes part of the margin visually rather than part of the padding.

Comment: For the record, when I answered the question, I interpreted the request as making the border look like part of the margin rather than part of the padding. I realize that other answers interpret the question as making a border _around_ the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Make your padding the size your your current padding + margin, then set your margin to 0 pixels. This will have the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible but if you want to enclose the margin within a border then there can be a workaround.
Enclose the element with span and set the border for that span element as,

```css
.inner{
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;   
}

.outer{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p class="inner">Hello</p>
</div>
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/h2uyL6tz/1/)

Comment: A paragraph element should not be contained inside of a span.

Comment: @kojow7 I wrote span instead of div in my answer please check now

Comment: @PatrickRoberts check out my updated answer, I wrote span instead of div in my answer and that's why it wasn't rendering

Comment: I don't like this approach as it uses HTML for styling rather than for structure, as it was intended. HTML should be used exclusively for structure and CSS should be used exclusively for styling where possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree my solution does not follow the conventional way but I guess this is a good out of the box answer for a question with an unusual demand.